# JS - Set variables value in function but use variable outside of it?

Tags: javascript

I need to set a variables value within a function, but use it outside of the function. Can this be done?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var myVar = something;
    });
    console.log(myVar);
});
```

Comment: Before your `.scroll` handler, add `var myVar;`. In the `.scroll` handler, don't use `var` (which will create a new variable). Note, however, that `myVar` will be undefined when you `log` it because it's not set until the scroll handler actually runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you need to first *declare* it outside of the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myVar;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
       myVar = something;
    });

    console.log(myVar);
});
```

Just know that `myVar` will only be updated *after* the scroll event is triggered.  So, your `console.log` will log `undefined` because it runs *before* the event runs and sets the variable.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**. Just declare variable outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  var myVar = "foo";
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function () {
          myVar = something;
      });
      console.log(myVar);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why make it global when containing it within the document ready would suffice?

Comment: He stated he wanted to use it outside of the function.  If he doesn't need it outside the function, then yes, I would declare it inside the function.

Comment: Outside the inner `$(window).scroll` function, not (necessarily) outside the `$(document).ready` since that where they are actually trying to use it.

Comment: I agree... good practice is to declare it to as small of a scope as possible.  However, my reading of the original question was to use it ouside of both the `$(window).scroll` function and the `$(document).ready` function.